# Lost update occured in serializable isolation level?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions, isolation-level

recently I've been learning about isolation levels at sql server. During watching one of tutorials I've noticed something strange, that I don't understand.
What I've been told is that in serializable isolation level there is no lost update, but at 2:30 isn't lost update accured after committing first transaction?: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9NVu17LjPSA&list=PL08903FB7ACA1C2FB&index=75

Please explain me what just happened in that moment

Comment: Where did you see lost update? First transaction committed 5 and second selected 5. Everything is fine.

Comment: Ok my bad but if this wasn't selecting in second transaction, but update it would still execute and made lost update

Comment: Incorrect @Rocket128 if transaction 2 was an update statement, it would not update until transaction 1 completed.

Answer (score 2):

The video in question explains that when the update is executed (transaction 1), it isn't commited. However, since the transaction isolation level is serializable, the read in transaction 2 for this same record can't read the value until the lock is released. Thus, transaction 2 is currently blocked by transaction 1. The lock is released when transaction 1 is committed, then transaction 2 can obtain the lock required for serializable isolation.

[From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

- Statements cannot read data that has been modified but not yet committed by other transactions.
- No other transactions can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until the current transaction completes.
- Other transactions cannot insert new rows with key values that would
  fall in the range of keys read by any statements in the current
  transaction until the current transaction completes.

Even more interesting is if you think serializable isolation means a transaction is executed only after the previous completes. [Paul White blogs on this in great detail.](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/04/t-sql-queries/the-serializable-isolation-level)